# C++ template class inheritance

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class C1
{
public:
    int n;
    C1(int a)
    {
        n=a;
    }
    T mat[50][50];
    void readmat()
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)for(j=1; j<=n; j++)cin>>mat[i][j];
    }
    void showmat()
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for(j=1; j<=n; j++)cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
class C2: public C1<T>
{
    C2(int a): C1(a) {};

};
```

Whenever I run it, I get the error:

> In constructor C2::C2(int)':
>
> error: class 'C2' does not have a field named 'C1'

If someone could explain to me what I did wrong, I would mostly appreciate it.

Comment: `C2(int a): C1(a) {};` should be `C2(int a): C1<T>(a) {};`

Comment: Could you please answer my post, too, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the template parameter to base class

```
template <class T>
class C2: public C1<T>
{
    C2(int a): C1<T>(a) {};

};
```

Comment: Could you please answer my post, too, please?